# Not Set Title of Navigation

Tags: react-native

I set tile in my Home.js file

```
 static navigationOptions={
        title:'Chat Chat'
  }
```

This is my App.js file

```
const AppStack=createStackNavigator({Home:HomeScreen, Chat:ChatScreen});
const AuthStack=createStackNavigator({Login:LoginScreen});


export default createAppContainer(createStackNavigator(
 {
    AuthLoading:AuthLoadingScreen,
    App:AppStack,
    Auth:AuthStack,
    
  },
  {
    initialRouteName:'AuthLoading'
  }
));
```

I load the component in 'AuthLoadingScreen.js'

```
export default class AuthLoadingScreen extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this._bootstrapAsync();
    }
   
    _bootstrapAsync=async()=>{
        User.phone=await AsyncStorage.getItem('userPhone');
        this.props.navigation.navigate(User.phone?'App':'Auth');
        
    };
    render(){
        return(
            <View>
                <ActivityIndicator/>
                <StatusBar barStyle="default"/>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

But when I running the project no set title of navigationOptions. It set titlr as App

[image]

How I change title 'App' to 'Chat Chat' when navigate to Home Component?

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is to set a title for the App stack like below

```
export default createAppContainer(createStackNavigator(
 {
    AuthLoading:AuthLoadingScreen,
    App:{
     screen:AppStack,
     navigationOptions: {
       title: 'Chat chat',
      },
    },
    Auth:AuthStack
  },
  {
    initialRouteName:'AuthLoading'
  }
));
```

Also try the headerTitle instead of title in home screen navigation options.